# wordpress how to retrieve a single custom field value from a custom field array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom fields that is actually an array.

I would like to get one single field value from this array.

When I do:
    $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_fields_array');
and then
    var_dump($meta); // debugging 
I can see the array

How can I get one single value from this array?

Comment: Do you know how to get a single value from an php array? Do the same for `$meta`

Comment: honestly I know how to do it via "row" number, like: echo $meta[5] instead I would like to do that via field name, like $meta['product_it']

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($meta)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution: the issue is that the custom fields values I need are actually serialized into a string. So if I unserialize them I'm able to get what I need:

```
$meta= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_array', true );
$myvalues = unserialize( $meta );
echo $myvalues[my_value];
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a value from an array instead of using

```
var_dump
```

Just echo out the value that you need, starting from 0 e.g.

```
<?php 
$meta = array('Best','Worst','Stuff');

echo $meta[1];
 ?>
```

In my case echo $meta[1] = Worst

now do the same for your code,if you just want to see the value that is

Comment: Actually it's a little bit more complex: when I do var_dumb I get this: array(1) { [0]=> string(...   so the array actually contains a string that is something like this: "a:6:{s:10:"difficulty";s:4:"easy" and so on. If I unserialize it I'm able to get the whole values (ex. easy, 12, computer, ... ecc) But I can't get only one specific value